# Django - no such column

Tags: django, models

I am a Django beginner and I got this error which I couldn't solve. 
I am simply trying to add a basic model Bar, which has a City and a Country.
this is models.py:

```
from django.db import models
# from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey, GroupedForeignKey

DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID = 1 # id of Israel
DEFAULT_CITY_ID = 1 # id of Herzeliyya
DEFAULT_BARNAME_ID = 1 # id of Bourbon Street

class Country(models.Model):
    # continent = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Europe")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country

class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country_of_city = models.ForeignKey(Country, default=DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city

class BarName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, default=DEFAULT_CITY_ID)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name        

class Bar(models.Model):    # The whole detailed BAR.
    country_of_bar = models.ForeignKey(Country, default=DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID)
    city_of_bar = models.ForeignKey(City, default=DEFAULT_CITY_ID)
    name_of_bar = models.ForeignKey(BarName, default=DEFAULT_BARNAME_ID)
```

this is the error which i get when trying to add a bar:

```
OperationalError at /admin/foos/bar/
no such column: foos_bar.country_of_bar_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/foos/bar/
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: foos_bar.country_of_bar_id
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 485
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

Comment: Did you [run migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/)?

Comment: So what Daniel is saying is that after you define / change your models, you need to tell Django to create the tables and columns in your database. You need to configure your database in your project's `settings.py` file, and then run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands in the documentation that Daniel pointed you to.

Comment: Yes, I did run 'makemigrations' and 'migrate'. What now?

Comment: @user1370384 Everytime I change models and try to make `migrations` and `migrate`, the command prompt is saying **no migrations to apply**. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @SrikarReddy, you'll probably have better luck starting a new question with additional details, like what Django version, etc.